# Number of Unique Rows in Subgroup

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `x` like this:

```
> data = data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4), x=c(1,1,0,0), y=c(1,1,0,1), id = c(22,22,33,33))
> data
   a x y id
1: 1 1 1 22
2: 2 1 1 22
3: 3 0 0 33
4: 4 0 1 33
```

I want to group by `id` and count the number of unique rows formed by `x` and `y` for each `id`.  Column `a` is irrelevant.  So the output I want is something like this:

```
   id count
1: 22 1
4: 33 2
```

I tried this but I get an error:

```
> data[, unique(list(x,y)),by='id']
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , unique(list(x, y)), by = "id") : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group
```

Comment: I think this is equivalent and would be faster on large data (as it avoids call to `unique` for each group: `unique(data, by=c("id", "x" , "y"))[, .N, by="id"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing `length`:

```
data[, length(unique(list(x,y))), by = 'id']
#    id V1
# 1: 22  1
# 2: 33  2
```

Regarding your question in the comment, this seems to work:

```
data[, length(unique(as.list(.SD))), by = "id", .SDcols = 2:3]
#    id V1
# 1: 22  1
# 2: 33  2
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is it possible to use with=FALSE as well so I can specify the columns as an index as opposed to names?  I have quite a few columns.

Comment: @mchangun, maybe you want something like `data[, length(unique(as.list(.SD))), by = "id", .SDcols = 2:3]`? (Not tested--just stepped away from my computer for a while.)